# CloudFront Distribution with ELB origin HTTP 502 (Bad Gateway)

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a CloudFront Distribution connected with a custom origin ELB (with EC2 instance). When executing  a request `curl https://xxx.cloudfront.net/atlassian-connect.json` a `HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway` response is returned.

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 587
Connection: keep-alive
Server: CloudFront
Date: Sun, 29 May 2016 14:32:18 GMT
Age: 23
X-Cache: Error from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 fb7ff691963d3e3600808dccbe4422d2.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: HymCU2TweM0e6O4bDhluvDOj0gd2BoAqCnDtVyTOZBz2wOIYHN-Qhg==
```

When sending a request (bypassing the CloudFront distribution) straight to the ELB I'm able to get the response that is expected:

```
curl  -kv https://xxx.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com/atlassian-connect.json
```

After trying to tweak some of the cloudfront distribution options I'm not able to get it to work.

Comment: The `-k` in your cURL command is concerning. Does it work without that? If your SSL isn't valid, CloudFront isn't going to connect.

Comment: You nailed it, as usual, @ceejayoz.

Comment: For me issue was that certificate for ELB was incorrect (was custom certificate, but the Origin URL for CloudFront was AWS own DNS: something124124.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The SSL certificate on your server is not usable in this configuration.

You're bypassing validation with curl, but CloudFront (sensibly enough) provides no such bypass mechanism.

Your cert must match *either* the origin hostname *or* the `Host:` header in the original request, if you have the `Host:` header whitelisted for forwarding to the origin.

> If your certificate doesn't contain any domain names that match either Origin Domain Name or the domain name in the Host header, CloudFront returns an HTTP status code 502 (Bad Gateway) to the viewer.

...and, it has to be current, valid, not self-signed, with a properly constructed trust chain:

> If the origin server returns an expired certificate, an invalid certificate or a self-signed certificate, or if the origin server returns the certificate chain in the wrong order, CloudFront drops the TCP connection, returns HTTP error code 502, and sets the X-Cache header to Error from cloudfront.

Citations are from http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/SecureConnections.html.

Comment: Headers have not been forwarded with the request. So the `Host:` header was missing in the request and the request failed.

Comment: I can't believe it took me too long to find out the certificate was the issue. I'm upvoting this, hopefully it will making to the first results of Google.

Answer (score 12):

In case the problem is not with the certificates (like in my case), it can be related to the headers not being passed to the origin. After setting `AllViewer` for the **Origin request policy** option in the CloudFront behavior setting (see picture), the 502 Bad Gateway error was gone.

[image]

Origin request policy values are further explained here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-origin-request-policies.html